# How to execute Test suit in TestNg and eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, selenium, testng

I am trying to work on TestNg with eclipse and selenium webdriver.

I created a package com.selenium.practice
I created 2 test classes Test1 and Test2 inside above package.
Then i created testng.xml in same package. Content of xml are as

```html
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite" verbose="1" >
  <test name="NameofMyTest" >
      <classes>
       <class name="com.selenium.practice.Test1" />
       <class name="com.selenium.practice.Test2" />
  </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

When i execute above xml using TestNg, no class is executed. But on eclipse console i received log as

===============================================
Suite

## Total tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Skips: 0

Could anyone help me on this please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The code written in testng.xml was perfect. I think there was some issue in building the project. i closed the eclipse, rebuild the project. after execution it worked fine.

Still one thing i observed is, in testng.xml we need to give complete classpath. Just a class name is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working perfectly to run Multiple suites using selenium.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="SuiteA"  > 
    <!-- suite name="Suite Name" --> 


                 <test name="TestA1" allow-return-values="true">
                         <classes>
                           <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                 <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteA.TestCaseA1" />
                         </classes>
                 </test>

                 <test name="TestA2" allow-return-values="true">
                         <classes>
                           <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                 <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteA.TestCaseA1" />
                         </classes>
                 </test>



    </suite>

    ************************

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="SuiteB"  > 
    <!-- suite name="Suite Name" --> 


                 <test name="TestB1" allow-return-values="true">
                         <classes>
                           <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                 <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteB.TestCaseB1" />
                         </classes>
                 </test>

                 <test name="TestB2" allow-return-values="true">
                         <classes>
                           <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                 <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteB.TestCaseB2" />
                         </classes>
                 </test>


    </suite>

    ***************************

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="SuiteC"  > 
    <!-- suite name="Suite Name" --> 


                 <test name="TestC1" allow-return-values="true">
                         <classes>
                           <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                 <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteC.TestCaseC1" />
                         </classes>
                 </test>

                 <test name="TestC2" allow-return-values="true">
                         <classes>
                           <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                 <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteC.TestCaseC2" />
                         </classes>
                 </test>


    </suite>

    ********************************

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="TestNG Dadadriver suite"  > 
    <!-- suite name="Suite Name" --> 


            <suite-files>
                   <suite-file path="./suiteA.xml" />
                   <suite-file path="./suiteB.xml" />
                   <suite-file path="./suiteC.xml" />

            </suite-files>


    </suite>
```

Comment: @user3717841 : Yes class name should be defined as Packagename.classname